# Mostrar o meu dispositivo físico conectado no Android Studio no logcat

Tags: android-studio, flutter, logcat

Depurar um código utilizando o Logcat é muito bom.

Devido a minha máquina não ter muitos recursos eu estou usando o dispositivo físico para testar meus apps.

Só esse dispositivo não aparece na lista de dispositivos conectados no Android Studio

O que do Androd SDK preciso configurar para que meu dispositivo físico apareça no Logcat?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sendo que ele aparece bem na barra principal do Android Studio

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço se puderem me ajudar

A aplicação que estou desenvolvendo é em Flutter

Comment: Caso seja Windows, seu dispositivo está sendo reconhecido no gerenciador de dispositivos?

Comment: Sim, está sendo reconhecido. Porque é por ele que estou debugando

Comment: Eu vi depois e também está na lista de dispositivos